# Handsontable: jquery merge headers, bug at horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, handsontable

im currently working with handsontable and python+django, i put a custom merged header with Javascript. And this should look like this.

But when i load the page.

[image]

BUT, when i scroll back and foward the error disappear magically.

[image]

This is the container div.

```
<div class="table-container" style="width: auto; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;margin-top: 20px;">
                                <div id="table-index"  data-productoscomerciales='{{productoscomerciales}}'></div>
                          </div>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
function createTable(data, container) {    

var str = '<tr id="header-grouping">'+'<th colspan="1"></th>'+'<th colspan="1"></th>'+'<th colspan="1"></th>'+'<th colspan="15">Inventario*</th>' + 
          '<th colspan="9">Producción*</th>'+'</tr>';  

return new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data.slice(2,data.length),
  minSpareRows: 1,
  rowHeaders: false,
  manualColumnResize: true,

  colHeaders: data[0],
  columns: data[1],

  colWidths: [150, 100, 130],
  contextMenu: false,
  afterRender  : function () {$('.htCore > thead > tr').before(str);},
  beforeRender: function() {
        while ($('#header-grouping').size() > 0)
                $('#header-grouping').remove();
    },
    afterColumnResize: function () {
        $container.handsontable('render');
    },
      afterGetColHeader: function() {
        while ($('.ht_clone_top.handsontable #header-grouping th').size() > 0)
           $('.ht_clone_top.handsontable #header-grouping th').remove();
    }    
});
```

}

Comment: are you using any special css files?

Comment: Hi ZakeDrioid, actually i am using the default handsontable CSS for the table.

http://handsontable.com/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's wrong. Remove the `afterRender` and it should fix itself. The problem you have is that you're trying to modify the html on the table that Handson renders, which is always a bad idea. Handson will re-render fairly frequently, like when you scroll or click, meaning that line is pretty useless after a few seconds of using the table.